# JAX-RS default @Produces

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, jax-rs, resteasy

Is there an application-wide way of the defaulting the @Produces annotation on all JAX-RS /resources?

I have a lot of classes that produce web services. Rather than put `@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})` on every one of them, I'd like to do it in a central place. That way I can add future producers in one place instead of having to modify every class.

I'm currently using Resteasy with Jetty.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately there is not. There might be a way to have a single MessageBodyWriter that produces the correct media type. The other way would be to have a root JAX-RS class mapped to Path("/") that produces the preferred type

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a bit old question but it could be helpful for someone else like me. As an addition to ccleve's solution you can use interfaces as well. Because of the multiple inheritance then you can combine multiple media types through interfaces. Example:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface IJsonResource {
}
```

and

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public interface IXmlResource {
}
```

Then in your concrete JAX-RS resource class:

```
public class SomeJaxRsResource implements IJsonResource, IXmlResource {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Create a parent /resource class, add the @Produces annotation to it, and then subclass it for the actual resources. Works fine.